# SWF - Params not working IE

Tags: internet-explorer, flash, parameters

I've been trying to pass parameters to IE when I put a SWF object on the page but nothing seems to work.

This is IE 7,8 & 9. The scaling, quality and wmode variables aren't triggered.

This is my code.

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" class="view" id="one-one" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" style="width: 1595px; height: 628px;">
<param name="movie" value="flash/one-one.swf" />
<param name="scale" value="ExactFit" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="quality" value="low" />
</object>
```

Comment: please specify what exactly does not work: the browser crashes or the object is not displayed or something else? What version of IE is that? Is your html document valid? Also, what should this mean:`<object width="100%" height="100%" style="width: 1595px; height: 628px;"></object>`, looks like too much styles for one object.

Comment: @Clergyman - I have updated my q. Sorry.

Comment: one of your problems is browser/HTML5 compatibility? because you're certainly using HTML5. Video obj is not supported but in IE9. See http://deepbluesky.com/blog/-/browser-support-for-css3-and-html5_72/ and particularly this http://deepbluesky.com/asx/ie8.jpg. Try to run it in firefox, so you can figure out wether this is just compatibility issue or something bigger is missing.

Comment: @Clergyman Yeah, im on mac safari, FF & Chrome with bootcamp IE. Works in every browser except IE... bahh so I need to adjust the <!doctype...> depending on what browser it is?

Comment: @Clergyman - Changing Doctype depending on what browser did not solve my issue.

I used PHP to detect browser.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be that you're missing '**codebase**' attribute of the object?
Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_object.asp section 'Playing SWF Videos Using Flash', and try something like

```
<object width="1595px" height="628px"
classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/
pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
<param name="SRC" value="flash/one-one.swf"></param>
<embed src="bookmark.swf" width="1595px" height="628px">
</embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code working in IE, Firefox, Chrome..I dont say this is answer for above question, but this is reference for someone who has similar problem..

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" 
id="Yourfilename" ALIGN=""  style="width:1170px;height:127px">
  <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="/assets/env1.swf">
  <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
  <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399>
  <EMBED src="/assets/env1.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 NAME="Yourfilename" style="width:1170px;height:127px" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

My flash started working in IE-8 with below line

```
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="/assets/env1.swf">
```

I resized flash in IE-8 by specifying style attribute in object like below.

```
 <OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" 
    id="Yourfilename" style="width:1170px;height:127px">
```